# Elastic Stack [docker-elk] docker entry-point index creation using API calls

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, elastic-stack

I'm working on a project using the elastic stack , elasticsearch logstash and kibana.
The goal now is to use docker to run the stack. based on this https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk i configured the docker-compose to run my own pipelines with my own parsing.

The problem i'm facing is automatic configuration (creating index templates and/or indices). I know i call use curl to do API calls, after a search i found out about the entry-point shell script, i tried copying the script from the official image and adding my curl -XPUT calls in there but it doesn't work.
So my next reflex was to open the CLI and type in my curl calls and it works fine.

So my question is how can i run my API calls automatically when the container starts , i'm pretty new with docker and the elastic stack.

thank you !

EDIT:

So i got it working with a basic bash image and curl installed with the RUN command on my Dockerfile.

now i have an issue with having the services communicate (i put them all in the same network) i'm probably doing it wrong so i'm getting :

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

edit :

updated my scripts to call elasticsearch:9200 without exposing ports and it works fine now !

i also think that the script is not waiting on elasticsearch to finish to execute the script.

Here is my docker-compose file :

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: volume
        source: elasticsearch
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: changeme
      # Use single node discovery in order to disable production mode and avoid bootstrap checks.
      # see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html
      discovery.type: single-node
    networks:
      - elk

  configurator:
    build:
      context: configurator/
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  logstash:
    build:
      context: logstash/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/config
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/pipeline
        target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/data
        target: /usr/share/logstash/data
    ports:
      - "5044:5044"
      - "5000:5000/tcp"
      - "5000:5000/udp"
      - "9600:9600"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - configurator

  kibana:
    build:
      context: kibana/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./kibana/config/kibana.yml
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - configurator

networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new handmade docker image (or use a good starting image), add the API calls you need to issue on startup to the startup script. Make sure, it verifies if is need to execute the calls or all is already done by a previous run.

Next add the image to your compse and make it depending on elasticsearch service with the `depends_on` option. This will ensure that your cluster is running before starting your 'init container'.

Now, when starting up, the required services will be started (if not already running) and after that the init container will start.

Optional: Make the init container not starting up by default but only if explicitly started. For a example have a look at the monitor service an the x-enabled option [here](https://github.com/docker/app/blob/ec9d985c3472f12facfd61543bd49dbe39a7e6ca/internal/packager/testdata/packages/packing.dockerapp/docker-compose.yml#L27)

It´s a good practice adding [healthchecks](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#healthcheck) to services. If you don´t, docker will assume service health just by the container state (running=healthly). But elasticsearch has a longer bootstrap procedure we need to wait for.

Add the following to elasticsearch:

```
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl --silent --fail localhost:9200/_cluster/health || exit 1"]
  interval: 30s
  timeout: 30s
  retries: 5
```

And add this to the configurator service:

```
depends_on:
  elasticsearch:
    condition: service_healthy
```

Comment: hi, thanks for taking the time to answer, but can you be more explicit about the startup scripts , that's what i'm not sure about. (because the image i'm using pulls an official image from elastic)

Comment: Oh now i got, you mean a new image with just an OS not a elasticsearch one, got it will work on it and get back here !

Comment: Exsctly, just a minimal image with curl support etc.

Comment: i used an image that comes with bash curl and SSL , but as soon as the compose starts all the other images run except this one and i have no idea why !

Comment: may I ask for the compose.yml?

Comment: i'm back, happy holidays, so i got my image working now i have issues with execution and networking, i'm updating the post !

Comment: happy holidays! probably it is just a timing issue/race condition. the configurator service starts as soon elasticsearch is available but still booting. it is a good practice to add healthchecks to services. I'll update my answer to show the healthcheck usage.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and information ! i am almost there ! now i have to deal with the networking issues, curl failed to connect to the host if i run the same curl calls on the host (my machine) it works fine but i can't get it to work from a container (service) to another.

Comment: the configurator service exposes the same port as elasticssearch service (9200:9200) - that can´t work. Can you also elaborate which call (example) works from your host but not from the service (which service)?

Comment: so if i understand this correctly, for elasticsearch we make the host 9200 equivalent to the local (container) 9200 , in my script my curl calls are to localhost:9200, i deleted the ports part in my tests, but the goal here is that i can call the hosts 9200, so i should do ports : 9200:some_other_port_locally ? (i tried that and i still get connection refused)

Comment: As both services are in the same elk network they are visible and available for each other by service name you used in compse file. so if you want to call elasticsearch from the configurator, use http://elasticsearch:9200 in the script. you don´t even need to expose any port, as all ports are visible by default within the elk network too. Only if you need the service reachable form your host, you will need to expose the port in order to call kibana using localhost:5601 for example.

Comment: the elasticsearch healthcheck uses localhost:9200, as it refers to itself. the configurator needs to call elasticsearch:9200 as it refers to a different service within the same network. and form your machine, you need to use locahost plus the port you have exposed, which is localhost:5601 in kibanas case

Comment: i have tried that (without exposing ports and by calling elasticsearch:9200) but it didn't work i deleted everything and built again and now it works as expected ! thanks for the help and patience !

Comment: Cheers! Great Work! Have Fun!